# How Recursion function deal with local variable inside fnction when function call it self?

Tags: c, recursion

I have seen the factorial prgrm . my question is whenever recursion is called how variable value is retrieved during each function call? Nd why we need to return 1 when number reaches to 1 .? If it return 1 then why it does not show output 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E.g code:

```
int fact(int n)
{
    if(n <= 1) return 1;
    return n*fact(n-1);
}
```

n is scoped locally, so in each revursive call is setted as retrieve in the funtion parameter, so fo 3:

```
for fact(3) -> n1 = 3
for fact(2) -> n2 = 2
for fact(1) -> n3 = 1

> Then fact(3) = n1*n2*n3 => 3*2*1 = 6
```

Comment: Ya gd recursion will stop at 1 but.. Here value of fact(1) will be return tonthe fact (2) and for fact(2) it will like 2*fact(1) nd here fact(1) is 1 so fact(2) will return 2*fact(1)=2 so fact will return 2 to fact(3) nd fact(3) will compute like this 3*fact(2)=3*2=6 so final ans 6 is returned                             m i correct????

Comment: Yes @DarshanMakwana, thats exactly what I explained in the answer :)